# How to call a Method from controller in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

How can I call a Method from my r_holidays_controller?

Here is my try in scripting it, but it won't work.

```
$(function () {
        $('#toright').click(function () {
            var sel = document.getElementById("left");
            var len = sel.options.length;
            var w_id = this.getAttribute('w_id');
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
                {
                if(sel.options[i].selected) 
                    {
                    $.ajax("/r_holidays/w_destroy", {holiday_id: sel.options[i].value, group_id: w_id}).done(function(data){});
                    }
                }
            history.go(0);
        })
      });
```

I think, there must be a mistake in my `$.ajax( ... )`.

Soes anyone have an Idea to get this working?
When checking my pathes, I realize, that my aren't listed...

```
r_holidays_path      GET     /r_holidays(.:format)           r_holidays#index
                     POST    /r_holidays(.:format)           r_holidays#create
new_r_holiday_path   GET     /r_holidays/new(.:format)   r_holidays#new
edit_r_holiday_path  GET     /r_holidays/:id/edit(.:format)  r_holidays#edit
r_holiday_path       GET     /r_holidays/:id(.:format)   r_holidays#show
                     PATCH   /r_holidays/:id(.:format)       r_holidays#update
                     PUT     /r_holidays/:id(.:format)   r_holidays#update
                     DELETE  /r_holidays/:id(.:format)   r_holidays#destroy
```

EDIT:

Here's my controller code:

```
class RHolidaysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_r_holiday, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @r_holidays = RHoliday.all
  end

  def new
    @r_holiday = RHoliday.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    render json: RHoliday.find_or_create(holiday_id: params[:holiday_id].to_s, group_id: params[:group_id].to_s) 
  end  

  def w_create
    @r_holiday = RHoliday.new(r_holiday_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @r_holiday.save
        format.html { redirect_to @r_holiday, notice: 'RHoliday was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @r_holiday }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @r_holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end  

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @r_holiday.update(holiday_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @r_holiday, notice: 'RHoliday was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @r_holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @r_holiday.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to holidays_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def w_destroy
    render json: RHoliday.where(holiday_id: params[:holiday_id].to_s, group_id: params[:group_id].to_s).destroy 
  end




  private
    def set_holiday
      @r_holiday = RHoliday.find(params[:id])
    end

    def holiday_params
      params.require(:r_holiday).permit(:holiday_id, :group_id)
    end

end
```

And the relevant line(s) in my routes.rb is just `resources :r_holidays`

Comment: can we see the controller code and the relevant part of routes.rb?

Comment: Did you add w_destroy action in your routes file?

Comment: I didn't. Where do I have to add it?
I've just added resources :r_holidays to my routes.rb.
What else do I need to add there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/r_holidays/w_destroy",
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {
      holiday_id: sel.options[i].value,
      group_id: w_id
    },
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  });
```

You need to pass ID of record that you want to delete. and then it will call method from url and you can find that record in a method what you have pass with data from $.ajax.

```
 url: "/r_holidays/:id/w_destroy"  I think you need to pass a Id here.

 var my_url = "/rholidays/" + <%= @object.id %> + "/w_destroy";
 pass my_url as url: my_url, in $.ajax
```

your method should contain.

```
 data = params[:holiday_id]
 group = params[:group_id]
 holiday = Holiday.find(data)
 holiday.destroy
```

This way you can destroy method. or rails provides a best ajax method (Rjs). why dont you try that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) syntax with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Try replacing your `$.ajax` with `$.get`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but it doesn't work.
I'm trying to do this, for creating/destroying rows in a table. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah. Is your action accessible by a GET route, or only a POST/PUT/DELETE?

Comment: $.get will follow the get route which routes to `r_holidays#show` you need to call with the `DELETE` method

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be right, but there is one thing you are missing here.

You can notice yourself that your controller receives requests like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. That means your .ajax method should specify the type of request you send.

If you want to invoke destroy action of your r_holidays controller you should try smth like this:

```
$.ajax("/r_holidays", type: 'DELETE', {holiday_id: sel.options[i].value, group_id: w_id}).done(function(data){});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: when I add this line, I get a Syntax error, because of type: 'DELETE'. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Chowlett is correct for GET and POST - replace 'ajax' with 'get'/'post'. Or use the full 'ajax' syntax by passing an object of settings: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Note that browser support for PUT and DELETE methods via AJAX has a questionable history, as it says in the jQuery.ajax API docs for the 'type' setting.

If your backend supports HTTP method emulation via POST, like Rails does, I have written a jQuery plugin for that with convenient $.put, $.patch, and $.delete methods:

https://github.com/adjohnson916/jquery-methodOverride

Check it out!