# execute ruby code on click of a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two buttons in my page.html.erb file that updates the values in a table.

```
<div class="container container-1">
<button class="_button _button-2">action1</button>
<button class="_button _button-3">action2</button>
</div>
```

When I press a button I want it to execute a piece of code in the pagecontroller and display the result in the table. I am able to do all these but struck at recognizing button. How do I execute ruby code on click of the buttons? I want to do it with rails not JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried ? If you are able to execute ruby code on button click then I guess you should change the question title as it misleads others.

Comment: @AlokSwain: I meant I am unable to figure out how do I call a method in my controller whenever a button is clicked.

Comment: Server sided code can be executed through AJAX. Rails guides has info which shows how to execute server sided code on button click, do go through that for a better understanding of how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a an AJAX request for that method, because Ruby-Code is serverside and The button-click is clientside.

I allready asked that in an earlier question:
[How to call a Method from controller in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763978/how-to-call-a-method-from-controller-in-rails)

Comment: Can't I do it without AJAX?

Comment: As I told you, (at least as far as I know) not.
You know the client-server relation?

The client executes the HTML and the JAVASCRIPT. The Server executes stuff like Ruby, Perl and so on. 
If you need to call a method, which is on the Server, you have to call it using AJAX.

Comment: Then what is the use of having `button_to` method in rails?

Comment: Check out the [button_to documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to).
The Problem is, that you should NOT use it anymore, because it will be deprected in the next Rail Update. Believe me, I had the same thaughts the last few weeks.
But it really is not that hard if you check out the Guide, mentioned by [Alok Swain](http://stackoverflow.com/users/301419/alok-swain)